# Always select true/higher value in LINQ statement group by (Multiple columns)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, grouping

Say I've got 2 lists that look something like

```
      ID | IsChipCollected | IsShirtCollected | IsPackCollected
A     0                 1                  0                 1
      1                 0                  1                 0
      2                 0                  0                 1      


B     0                 0                  1                 0
      1                 0                  0                 1
      2                 1                  1                 1
```

Basically I need to compare and merge the 2 lists and if a certain flag has been set to say true in B, i should select it instead of A

I know how to achieve this with a single column, but I'm struggling wrapping my head around doing it in a scenario with 2+ columns

```
  var result = A.Concat(B)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsShirtCollected).First())
```

I'll update my code sample if i make any progress on this, (as I'm currently still hacking away :P)

**Expected Result**

```
     ID | IsChipCollected | IsShirtCollected | IsPackCollected
      0                 1                  1                 1
      1                 0                  1                 1
      2                 1                  1                 1
```

Comment: So what should the results be in your example?

Comment: List A actually has a lot of other fields (just left them out to make the question more readable. My result set would basically be true flags depending on the columns that have true in them an any of the sets.)

Comment: Please actually include the desired results in the question, in addition to your explanation.  You are not being very clear, and since you haven't actually shown what the results will be for the inputs you've provided there is no good way for us to know if we understand you or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = A.Concat(B)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => new {//or new <A and B's generic type>, then change the underCode with proper case
             id = g.Key,
             isShipCollected = g.Max(m => m.IsChipCollected),
             isShirtCollected = g.Max(m => m.IsShirtCollected),
             isPackCollected = g.Max(m => m.IsPackCollected)
    });
```

**Edit**

Following Servy's (good) idea (changing 1 / 0 to boolean values)

```
var result = A.Concat(B)
       .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
       .Select(g => new { 
            id = g.Key,
            isShipCollected = g.Any(m => m.IsChipCollected == 1),
            isShirtCollected = g.Any(m => m.IsShirtCollected == 1),
            isPackCollected = g.Any(m => m.IsPackCollected == 1)
        });
```

Comment: I would use `Any` rather than `Max`.  It's much more semantically clear if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would be faster/slower than a concat/groupby, but technically the operation that you're performing is a `Join`, so it makes more sense in terms of readability to actually perform that join.

```
var query = listA.Join(listB, item => item.ID, item => item.ID,
    (a, b) => new
    {
        ID = a.ID,
        IsChipCollected = a.IsChipCollected | b.IsChipCollected,
        IsShirtCollected = a.IsShirtCollected | b.IsShirtCollected,
        IsPackCollected = a.IsPackCollected | b.IsPackCollected,
    });
```

Comment: Thanks again, :) good answer as well, but your answer does remove any records that doesn't exist in list A/B. They need to be present in both lists for a join to be effective (that's why I used a concat and group by, as this isn't always the case in my instance)